Is EOS R7 USB power supply currently under vendor lock-in?
I upgraded the firmware of my Canon EOS R7 to version 1.6.0, whose documentation says that it's possible to charge the battery on-body over USB power supply. However, all the documentation seem to suggest a PD-E1 adaptor is needed to do so, and third party power bricks and cables aren't mentioned. Is EOS R7 USB power supply currently under vendor lock-in?

Please define what you mean by vendor lock-in?

@MichaelC That's a very simple concept! Once you're using some vendor's product, you will be forced to use that vendor's accessories due to the vendor using non-standard and proprietary interfaces on their products.

Thank You. I've never heard the term used that way before. Since PD is a standard in the USB specification, it's not proprietary.

I don't know your specific model but, my M6 Mark II requires specifically USB Power Delivery (not the Qualcomm stuff) and I've been able to charge it with a laptop charger and a GaN high-power PD charger.  I think it may require chargers that can provide more than the minimum 5v, possibly 9v+.  It does not seem to charge off lower-power phone chargers, but thos might just be Qualcomm Quick-Charge again.
Given the name of the recommended charger is PD-E1 (for Power Delivery) I assume the same applies to your camera.  Any higher-power PD charger like a laptop or Switch charger should work.

I managed with a Thunderbolt 3 cable.

I would be very surprised  that there is a lock-in. USB charging and USB power delivery are standards so you can't say you are supporting them without being compatible with others.
Also, there is a whole ecosystem of chips to support this, so it wouldn't be economically sound to develop your own thing which would require somewhat costlier custom electronics.
This said why don't you connect you camera to your computer (it should have a USB port that doubles as a charging port for external devices) and see if t charges?

xenoid, this is possible. In power supply/cable there is chip which send ID when negotiate voltage/power and (by my experience) some mobile phones do not switch to fast charging when the powersupply/cable is not from the same brand.

@RomeoNinov No, see here. 1) for plain USB, shorting the two data lines with a 200Ω resistance indicates that the port can provide "unlimited" power (more than 15W). 2) Recent USB implements a more complex scheme top negotiate a higher voltage (some more power without drawing more current, which could damage the smallish USB-C connector). Of course all this works only if both sides implement the standard (cheap no-name chargers likely don't).

@RomeoNinov Interesting video on USB Power delivery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpxYl2-PtLU

Check here and search for keyword chip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C  And this is the way unit can recognize the cable.

Also other Canon cameras with USB C charging just require Power Delivery, but I think at the non-base voltages so resistor termination tricks wouldn't be enough.  I've charged from a laptop charger easily enough.
